# Is it possible to get the serial number of a GPU without opening the case?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, gpu

I have an Nvidia GPU GTX 470 - Can I get it's serial number with out opening the case?

**EDIT**
Thanks for all the comments: I tried the Device path as well as the WMIC command (which are the same actually)
Value returned from the WMIC command

```
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 470  PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_06CD&SUBSYS_079F10DE&REV_A3\4&2F1C4782&0&0018
```

The WMIC (device path is) **2F1C4782** which is translated to: **790382466** (converted to decimal).

My card SN is: **101500021088** - I think this does not get the correct values.

Comment: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1C03&SUBSYS_62643842&REV_A1\4&1BA317CD&0&XXXX last 4 digis removed, what is mt serial number?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Note:**  Note that this technique only works if the hardware manufacturer implements it.  I can't give a percentage of accuracy, but I would guess the big players would implement it.  If it's not implemented, Windows will generate a unique number instead.

**Method 1 - Device Manager**

Open the Windows Device Manager.  Find your video card under Display Adapters.  Double-click on it.  Under the "Details" tab, select the "Device Instance Path" property.

**Method 2 - WMI**

Using WMI, at the command line, run the following command.

```
wmic PATH Win32_VideoController GET Description,PNPDeviceID
```

**Method 3 - Use a Tool**

A program like [SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/) will grab the PNP Device ID for you, but it won't do the parsing for the serial number.

**Parsing It**

Looking at the PNPDeviceID value, break it up by "\".

- The first piece it the bus type.  For me, it is PCI.
- The second section describes the card.  There's a vendor code, model number, etc.
- The last section contains a number separated by ampersands.  The serial number is the second number in that list, formatted in hex.

Comment: There are "PNPDeviceID"s for other things too.  Replace "Win32_VideoController" with "Win32_DiskDrive" to see the IDs for your disk drives.  If possible, you may want to verify the numbers against something you can look at to make sure you're parsing the number correctly.

Comment: [Further research shows](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wdk/thread/79ae8d7f-6562-4df8-b00b-fe410342f71c/) that the value in the PNPDeviceID may be just an autogenerated number made up by Windows to uniquely identify the card.  So, it is important to try and verify what you see.

Comment: *wait* ... so do any of these methods conclusively provide the product serial number?  Because if the case must be opened to verify that the serial number is correct, you have defeated the purpose of the question... which was to find a method of determining the serial number without opening the case.

Comment: @BonGart This technique is used to determine serial numbers on USB hard drives.  It may also work on video cards.  You are correct though that, depending on the device manufacturer, this may not properly identify the serial number.

Comment: So... you didn't try it yourself first to see if it actually does produce the serial number of your own video card?

Comment: @BonGart I only have integrated graphics on my machine, so I could not confirm it for sure.  If anyone can confirm this for sure, that would be great.

Comment: @BonGart I don't mind opening the case once to verify that this method works, if I can proof that it is correct for 100's other systems :-) for now it doesn't work, so back to square 1

Comment: I don't know if this was the case in the past but Elliot's answer worked for me with Titan RTX. `nvidia-smi --format=csv --query-gpu=name,serial`. If someone else can confirm this works with other recent cards, this answer should be updated.

Comment: pnpdeviceid is NOT the manufacturer's serial number of the device.

Answer (score 4):

For some Nvidia GPUs you can use a command like this. I believe this works on all Quadro and Titan cards, but not GTX “gaming” cards. The nvidia-smi tool is included with the Nvidia driver.

```
nvidia-smi --format=csv --query-gpu=name,serial,pci.bus_id
```

Comment: Worked on my Tesla P100, matched the serial number on the back of the card.

Comment: For the RTX 4000-series it only returns "[N/A]" in the place of serial :(

Answer (score 3):

I contacted **Nvidia** via chat-support on this subject, and unfortunately the official answer to your question is no:

> the only way to get the serial number of the graphics card is, it will be written on the graphics card hardware or the
>   box of purchase.

[chatlog from http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/chat/chat_landing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJAU5.png)

Comment: I don't know if this was the case in the past but Elliot's answer worked for me with Titan RTX. `nvidia-smi --format=csv --query-gpu=name,serial`

Answer (score 0):

c:\ nvidia-smi --format=csv --query-gpu=name,serial,pci.bus_id
name, serial, pci.bus_id
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080, 0322916107542, 00000000:03:00.0

That worked on a GTX1080 on windows 10x64 pro, but it is the wrong S/N :(

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1086733)