# How to uniquely identify GPUs (of the same model) on Linux?

Tags: linux, gpu, amd-radeon

I have multiple AMD Radeon GPUs (of the same model) on Linux. I'd like to be able to uniquely identify them, so that if I swap them between PCIe slots, or even between machines, I'll know which one is which without tracking them physically.

Is it possible to get a unique ID (e.g. the serial number) of a GPU on Linux? `lspci`, `dmidecode` and `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:nn:00.0/` don't seem to give anything useful for this purpose. I could also insert an unique ID into the empty space of the BIOS image, but doing so will likely void the warranty.

I'm aware of [the similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/469216/is-it-possible-to-get-the-serial-number-of-a-gpu-without-opening-the-case), but mine is on Linux and I can use any unique IDs, not just the serial number.

Answer (score 0):

Dell has [a document](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/b/techcenter/archive/2012/12/21/listing-devices-by-pci-add-in-slots-under-linux.aspx) that describes how to identify devices by slot on Linux.

- Run `dmidecode –t slot` and match Bus Address and Designation for populated PCI slots then…
- Run `lspci –s` to get info about device at the Bus Address for a given PCI slot.

Or use their [bash script](http://linux.dell.com/cgi-bin/cgit.cgi/sys-admin-tools.git/tree/list-pcie-ports.sh)

---

**Update**: Testing this further shows that this can identify the model of video cards, but can't distinguish between identical cards.

Comment: The OP already mentioned that neither `lspci` nor `dmidecode` help. If you know how to use these tools to get the info, please edit your answer to explain how.

Comment: spuder has a fine answer, @terdon. Both the bash script and Dell's document address the OP, no reason to disparage this answer. +1 for me.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I was not disparaging as such, but: 1) Link answers are [discouraged](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer), it is better to copy the relevant info into the answer (especially for such a small document) 2) the OP mentions both tools and specifically states that they did not help. I also tried this on my Dell laptop and couldn't figure out how to link `dmidecode` output to `lspci`'s. Therefore, this answer just suggests the OP do what (s)he has already done without explaining how to do it or giving any extra information at all. How is it a fine answer?

Comment: @terdon He provides a **new** document, a **new** bash script, info on how to use two instruments in a novel way. Whether they work or not is a subject for discussion, not for terse dismissal.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I was not terse. I politely (note the _please_) asked that spuder edit the answer to explain how to use the tools suggested. I did not downvote nor leave a disparaging comment, let alone a terse dismissal. That the proposed solution does not work IS a problem, how could it not be? The bash script is neither useful nor new because it also uses the `dmidecode` command whose output does not seem to contain the necessary info. That's why we _test_ our answers before posting them. This is simply a direct copy/paste of a post on Dell's forum, has not been tested and does not work.

Comment: @terdon Fine, this is constructive criticism, let us leave it at this.